# Modifying smooth curve with Anchor points

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I wish to emulate [this](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/splines.html) effect in Xcode with Swift. After some research I managed to find some articles about drawing smooth curves using a set of points .But I am still unclear about how I could to **dynamically modify curves** when the user touches/holds the screen.

**Question :**

I know how to make a smooth Bezier curve, but how can I add gesture recognizers such that by dragging the curve its shape changes.

I only need someone to point me in the right direction. Is there a guide or article in particular that could be useful?

Comment: You have a *very* good answer. Please understand that you simply *cannot* add gestures to a bezier path.

Comment: But there must be some way to recreate the  effect  here : http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/splines.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create transparent `ControlPointView` for every control point of the curve with a size of 50*50pt, so that users can easily tap them and drag.
2. Add a small image in the middle of every `ControlPointView`, so that users can see where the control point is located.
3. Add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on every `ControlPointView` and handle it in view controller.
4. Use centers of control points to rebuild `UIBezierPath` every time gesture recognizer's state is changed.

Comment: Thanks , I will try it out .